# .net core Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable)

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-core

I have no problem implementing the project in Local And it runs well. But when I published this project and running on the IISو i get the this error:
**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable)**

my startup class is :

```
.
.
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
.
.
```

and my View :

```
url: "/controller/test",
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "json",
            data: { id: id },
```

and my controller return :

```
return Json(new { data = mydata, recordsTotal = param.iDisplayLength, recordsFiltered = rowsCount });
```

Comment: check with the deployed server

Comment: Seems like the content-type which sent from the client is not supported by the Server.

Comment: Fail to reproduce the issue , did you use the [ApiController] above your Controller ? Could  you share more details about view and controller that can reproduce the issue ?